# ionic cordova prepare ios throws error as macos-release/index.js const [name, version] = nameMap.get(release);

Tags: ios, ionic4

**While running ionic cordova shows error in macos-release/index.js file**

```
> cordova prepare ios
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/macos-release/index.js:26
    const [name, version] = nameMap.get(release);
                            ^

TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
    at macosRelease (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/macos-release/index.js:26:26)
    at osName (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/os-name/index.js:21:18)
    at new Insight (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/insight/lib/index.js:37:13)
    at new RelentlessInsight (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/telemetry.js:31:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/telemetry.js:39:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
```

Comment: My issue get cleared after updating the cordova version...